# Can you have a method that takes a single parameter of multiple generics?

Tags: java, generics

Can you have a method that takes a single parameter of multiple generics?

Imagine the following interfaces and classes:

```
interface IOne<T> {
}

interface ITwo<T> {
}

class ClassA<T> implements IOne<T>, ITwo<T> {
}

class ClassB<T> implements IOne<T>, ITwo<T> {
}
```

These two interfaces and classes are part of Spring, so I cannot change them.

now I have a method which I do control:

```
void MyMethod(??? inst) {
   inst.someMethodFromIOne()
   inst.someMethodFromTwo()
}
```

is this possible? I can of course do `IOne<T> inst` or `ITwo<T> inst`, but is there a way to do both?

Unfortunately Spring does not have a common base class or common interface between the two. I was thinking of maybe creating a facade interface that implements both and writing two implementations, one for ClassA and one for ClassB that forwards the calls, but there are a lot of methods in those interfaces.

Any other option?

Comment: is the [tag:java] tag correct? `class ClassA<T> : implements IOne<T>, ITwo<T>` is not valid in Java

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `inst` to be something that implements both `IOne<T>` and `ITwo<T>`?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, exactly.

Comment: *obviously* , since there are no other languages/frameworks like Kotlin, Processing, AspectJ, C#, Spring-Boot, Android, Scala, ... we also never have seen any (lots of) question with wrong tags on this site  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method that takes two type parameters. One is used for for the `T` in `IOne<T>` and `ITwo<T>`. The other is used for the type of `inst`, which will have *two* bounds.

```
<T, U extends IOne<T> & ITwo<T>> void MyMethod(U inst) {
   inst.someMethodFromIOne();
   inst.someMethodFromTwo();
}
```

Of course, it could also be

```
<T extends IOne<?> & ITwo<?>>
```

or

```
<T, U, V extends IOne<T> & ITwo<U>>
```

depending on what you want.

Comment: Hmm.... it DOES accept the two interface types, but it didn't work out as I thought it would. `inst.someMethodFromOne().someMethodFromTwo()` doesn't work because `inst.someMethodFromOne()` returns an `IOne` rather then an `IOne/ITwo`. I guess I'll have to go the facade route to make that work?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Well I don't know what `someMethodFromOne` is here. In any case, `someMethodFromOne` just returns whatever type it is declared to return. You can't change that no matter what you do in `MyMethod`.

Comment: long story short, IOne and ITwo are both fluent interfaces. ClassA and ClassB implement both... but the way Spring set it up, its `IOne<T> someMethodFromIOne()` and `ITwo<T> someMethodFromITwo()` so chaining the calls with both interfaces doesn't work. Without using this trick, `someMethodFromIOne()` would return the concrete class that implemented both.

Comment: But I think this will actually work though :)... basically I have to split things up. Chain the `IOne` methods and then chain the `ITwo` methods in a separate call. This ends up working because the method calls update state on the same object. It does suck that I can't chain the calls, but better then creating multiple facades.

Comment: Basically trying to generically take multiple Spring db query types in the same method. `JPQLQuery<T>` and say `SpringDataMongodbQuery<T>`.